# Display a message on weekends only (PHP) (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to find the answer to this.

Basically I want to echo a message on a Saturday and Sunday only.

But have no idea how to identify Saturday and Sunday with php.

**EDIT:** Found the simple answer using javascript:

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
switch(date.getDay()){
    case 0: document.write("sunday!"); break;
    case 6: document.write("saturday!"); break;
    default: document.write("any other week day");
}
</script>
```

Works brilliantly.

Comment: What PHP? you didn't even show us any single line of code. You need to give us **any** clue. We cannot help you otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function in PHP to get the current day.

```
$currentDay = date('w'); // Get current weekday
```

That returns an integer from 0 - 6 where 0 is Sunday and 6 Saturday (Depending on your servers timezone).

Comment: Thanks, this will get me to the right direction.

Comment: I have edited the question, but still can't seem to work. I know there's a minor mistake in my code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Print out the current day and check the number. It's depending on your timezone, so it could be that the first day is a monday so saturday would be number 5.